# Movie about stranded people on an island with dog-like monsters and Japanese WW2 bunkers

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie only once, and I didn't see the whole thing. It was in English — it was not translated from other language, but it could be  American, British, Australian, anything. I saw it on a local cable channel.

The notable features were:

1. Possibly made in late 90s to early 2000s.
2. A group of people on a Pacific island (not the storyline of LOST), the people might have come by their own will and were possibly unable to leave (not exactly sure about this)
3. The island is infested with swarms of dog-like monsters. **Literally swarms, by the hundreds and thousands**. The animals are **not a result of any scientific research or experiment**.
4. There are World War II-era Japanese bunkers and machine gun weapons which the survivors use. There are even Japanese army records of the creatures and possibly the Japanese WWII base was destroyed / left in ruin by the creatures.

What is the name of this movie??? Any ideas???

Comment: When did you actually watch the movie? Did it seem to be an American movie/was it in English?

Comment: dont know if american / british / australian movie. but it was in english..

Comment: This sounds like a SyFy channel movie. I feel like I would have heard of it had it been a big budget job. Do you think you might have seen it on the SyFy channel? Or maybe even the Horror channel?

Comment: saw it on a local cable channel.. (i.e. the channels that the cable tv service providers give for running advertisements in the bottom ticker area)..

Comment: “The animals are not a result of any scientific research or experiment.” How do you/the characters know that?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the characters know this because from some old records they found from japanese army records which report of the infestation..

Comment: @RicoRicochet - What do you mean by "dog like"?  Are they small and furry?  Do they bark?  Are they shaped like dogs, or like people or werewolves?  When did you see it?

Comment: Size - Mid sized (waist height of average human), fur - yes(coat of fur on the body like a fox) but not furry like a Bear or Bantha.. They did not bark but made growling noise.. they are quadripedal but have stronger hind legs.. they can use their fore arms to attack as well.. I saw it 10 years back appx...

Answer (score 4):

[The Breed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Breed_(2006_film)) was released in 2006 but otherwise could fit.

**ii. a group of people in a pacific island (not the storyline of LOST), the people might have come by their own will and were possibly unable to leave (not exactly sure about this)**

Five friends go to an island by seaplane for a holiday.  Later, when they try to leave, the seaplane is surrounded and they can't reach it.

**iii. The island is infested by swarms of dog like monsters. Literally swarms, by the hundreds and thousands. The animals are not a result of any scientific research or experiment.**

The characters are constantly under attack by vicious dogs.

**iv. There are world war II era Japanese bunkers and machine gun weapons which the survivors use. There are even Japanese army records of the creatures and possibly the japanese WWII base was destroyed / left in ruin by the creatures.#**

The characters discover an old army base used to breed attack dogs.

[The Pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pack_(1977_film)) was released in 1977 and also features the island + vicious dogs combination, but has no army base that I know of.

Comment: after reading the story in the wiki article i can say this may be it, will try to get some videos from youtube.. but i can clearly remember the survivors using machine guns in guard towers / bunkers..

Comment: I've seen the Breed, it has about 30 regular dogs. The OP clearly mentions **dog like monsters** by the **hundreds and thousands**.

Comment: and plus those were monsters, not genetically enhanced dogs.. possibly cave dwelling / underground monsters..

Comment: And The Pack is about a family trapped in a house surrounded by dogs. Both of these movies are just horror movies with dogs that don't sound a thing like the description in the question.

Comment: saw the trailer of the breed [2006] on youtube... definitely NOT the one :(

Comment: "List Of The Deaths" - Lol.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're referring to the remake of [The Island of Dr Moreau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Dr._Moreau_%281996_film%29).

**i. possibly made in late 90s to early 2000s.**

The remake was made in 1996.

**ii. a group of people in a pacific island (not the storyline of LOST), the people might have come by their own will and were possibly unable to leave (not exactly sure about this)**

> Edward Douglas (David Thewlis) survives a plane crash in the Java Sea and is eventually rescued by a passing boat.

(snip)

> Douglas tries to escape by boat, but finds it overrun with rat-like creatures and gives up.

**iii. the island is infested by swarms of dog like monsters**

There are multiple hybrid monsters. Some of them are dog-like.

[image: dog like monsters]

[image: more dog like monsters]

**iv. there are world war II era japanese bunkers and machine gun weapons which the survivors use.**

The labs look more modern, but the above-ground settings look very WW2 era. There are guards with guns, as you can see in the trailer below.

Comment: umm sorry, but seeing the screenshot of monsters I am really confident this is not the one I saw. I am posting a few more edits to my question.

Answer (score 2):

It might be *[The Lost Tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Tribe_(2010_film))* ([review](http://horrornews.net/18422/film-review-the-lost-tribe-2009/the-lost-tribe-2009-movie-5/)), a 2010 remake of the 2009 film variously titled *After Dusk They Come*, *The Tribe*, and *The Forgotten Ones*.

> While on their way to Asia to close a business deal, five friends (Anna, Tom, Joe, Alexis, and Chris) rescue a man that's been left to drift at sea. Injured and in shock, the stranger overrides the yacht's autopilot and attempts to change the vessel's course, but instead wrecks the boat on a rock and the vessel sinks. The castaways wash ashore on the beach of an uncharted island and attempt to contact the Coast Guard over the yacht's radio. Before the Coast Guard can arrive, the body of the stranger vanishes from the grave the other survivors had laid him to rest in. Needing some time to himself, Tom wanders into the jungle and is attacked by an unseen assailant. During the attempt to find Tom the next day Alexis is killed by the jungle's inhabitants and Chris is taken. Joe and Anna discover a nefarious plot by the Vatican to cover up a research team's discoveries on the island before Joe is murdered by an assassin sent by the Catholic Church. Anna is then left by herself to survive on the island and uncover its secrets.

Comment: Could you please include some more details to help the questioner figure out whether this is the right film?

Comment: Please add a summary or some details about this film, e.g. by quoting from the link provided, so that we can tell how closely it matches the film described in the question. We tend to discourage link-only answers here, since if the link goes dead the answer is rendered essentially useless. You may be interested to read [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394) on answering story-ID questions.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but it is surely not the one. There was no plot point showing intervention by religious organizations.

Comment: I see no mention of dogs, so I doubt this is the right one, but providing details in case it helps someone who's actually looking for this film.

Answer (score -1):

“The Killer Shrews”. 1959....
https://archive.org/details/The_Killer_Shrews

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you [edit] and expand your answer to explain why you think this is the right film? For example, you could specify any plot points in the film which match the description given in the question.

Comment: :) Again, we're looking for explanations, not pointing at something and saying "this". Is there an island? Dog-like monsters? WW2 bunkers?